# How can I get the numbers to be different every time, and for the program to quit when entering a negative number?

Tags: c++

I need to figure out how to make the program quit when a negative number is entered, and how to get the random numbers to be different on every question... `

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numQs = 0,
        answer = 0;
    double number1, number2, sum;
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    number1 = 1 + rand() % 100;
    number2 = 1 + rand() % 100;
    sum = number1 + number2;
    
    cout << "Welcome to the 3rd grade addition test!" <<endl;
    cout << "How many questions would you like? ";
    cin >> numQs;
    cout << "(You may enter a negative number at any time to quit early.)" << endl;
    while (numQs > 0){
        for(int Qs = 1; Qs <= numQs; Qs++){
            cout << number1 << " + " << number2 << " = "; //<< sum << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if(answer == sum){
                cout << "correct!"<<endl;
            }else{
                cout << "incorrect, sorry"<<endl;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `srand(time(NULL))` once at the beginning.

Comment: You don't need while, you can just use break if answer is less than 0.

Comment: The latter can be acomplished by not setting the same seed everytime and ideally using `<random>` too.

Comment: To get 100% unique random numbers: Make a list of all valid numbers. Apply the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (implemented as [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) in the C++ Standard Library.) to the list. When you use a number remove it from the list. See [`std::iota` for a great example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota#Example).

Comment: Oh thank you, taking off the while, and just making another case with the break helped!

Comment: I suggest you use `<random>`, it's much better than C's `<ctime>`

Comment: It's not that ctime is bad, it's using something predictable like time as a seed for a random number generator that's bad. Anyone with a clock and knowledge of the Standard library implementation used can predict the sequence that will be generated with extremely high reliability. Worse, `rand`'s randomness guarantees suck. Here's a great presentation on just how bad `rand` can get and how to use the modern replacements: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)